# Return most frequent string value for each group

Tags: r, summarization

```
a <- c(rep(1:2,3))
b <- c("A","A","B","B","B","B")
df <- data.frame(a,b)

> str(b)
chr [1:6] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B"

  a b
1 1 A
2 2 A
3 1 B
4 2 B
5 1 B
6 2 B
```

I want to group by variable `a` and return the most frequent value of `b`

My desired result would look like

```
  a b
1 1 B
2 2 B
```

In `dplyr` it would be something like

```
df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize (b = most.frequent(b))
```

I mentioned `dplyr` only to visualize the problem.

Comment: OK, I found it myself `df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize (b =names(which.max(table(b))))`

Comment: how do you get the counts as well.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli: To get the count as well, simply use `max(table(b))`. Full code would be: `df %>% group_by(a) %>% 
  summarize (b =names(which.max(table(b))),
             count_b = max(table(b)))`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The key is to start grouping by both `a` and `b` to compute the frequencies and then take only the most frequent per group of `a`, for example like this:

```
df %>% 
  count(a, b) %>%
  slice(which.max(n))

Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: a

  a b n
1 1 B 2
2 2 B 2
```

Of course there are other approaches, so this is only one possible "key".

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution. Not really working. the function will only return the maximum n row, not maximum row per group. In this case, there is a draw --so you can see 2 rows(both n is 2, if group A==1 maximum b==B n is 3 and group A==2, maximum b==B is 2 then you will only have one row)

Comment: I think @talat may have forgot a line of code. Pipe the output of count into group_by before piping them into slice

Answer (score 10):

Other answers ignore tied frequencies
What works for me:

```
# A and B are tied
a <- c(rep(1:2,5))
b <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C")
df3 <- data.frame(a,b)

library(data.table)
setDT(df3)[ , .N, by=.(a, b)][ , .SD[ N == max(N) ], by = a] # includes ties

library(dplyr)
df3 |>
  group_by(a) |>
  count(b) |>
  top_n(1) # includes ties
```

Comment: Thank you but you need to be careful with duplicates

Comment: This doesn't work for me.. I get the wrong output. Probably because of duplicates

Answer (score 2):

`by()` each value of `a`, create a `table()` of `b` and extract the `names()` of the largest entry in that `table()`:

```
> with(df,by(b,a,function(xx)names(which.max(table(xx)))))
a: 1
[1] "B"
------------------------
a: 2
[1] "B"
```

You can wrap this in `as.table()` to get a prettier output, although it still does not exactly match your desired result:

```
> as.table(with(df,by(b,a,function(xx)names(which.max(table(xx))))))
a
1 2 
B B
```