# Include Most frequent item in a column in groupby on multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a df with below columns:

```
first_Date   Profit  Quantity  Discount  Segment
2012-01-01    23       24        45        seg1
2019-01-01    45       33        99        seg2 and so on
```

I perform groupby on first date column and find sum of profits, sum of quanitites, sum of discounts and most frequenct value of segment. Code made so far:

```
  group2<-df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(first_date), 
         year_mon = format(first_date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  group_by(first_date) %>%
  summarise(sum_profit = sum(Profit), 
            sum_quantity = sum(Quantity), 
            sum_discount = sum(Discount),
            )
```

Last column segment has not been captured here. I want to include the most frequent value of segment corresponding to each date above. How to do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode)

Comment: Pls fit the same thing inside this code..Unable to do that...I need the mode to be inside the code block...I dont know how to embed the function inside this block

Comment: `mode_segment=Mode(Segment)`

Comment: mode does not work

Comment: one option,df %>% 
  group_by(first_Date) %>% count(Segment)%>%
  slice(which.max(n))

Comment: you can use this link too,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922195/return-most-frequent-string-value-for-each-group