# Count occurrences in column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with large number of observations. The follow dataframe is just a smaller version of it. the dput output is given below

```
structure(list(Tags = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1), County = c("USA", 
"UK", "USA", "UK", "USA", "UK")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want R to display the top 10 numbers that appear and the number of times they appear.
Currently i am using the following code

```
table(Data$Tags)
```

While my dataset has a lot many observations than this one hence I want the top ten.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return most frequent string value for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922195/return-most-frequent-string-value-for-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply `sort()` and `head()` to the output of `table()`, e.g.,

```
head(sort(table(Data$Tags), decreasing=TRUE), 10)
```

Comment: Also is there any way to display this using a bar graph?

Comment: @AK1234 Do `barplot(result, col=4, main='Top 10')`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is `dplyr` version using `slice_max` with an example dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

as_tibble(sample(1:10, size = 300, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  count(value, sort = TRUE, name="myCount") %>% 
  slice_max(myCount, n=10)
```

```
   value myCount
   <int>   <int>
 1     7      39
 2    10      36
 3     3      33
 4     9      33
 5     8      31
 6     6      30
 7     4      29
 8     2      25
 9     5      25
10     1      19
```